# The safest, cheapest way to get to MEX airport from UNAM

Tags: safety, transportation, airport-transfer, mexico-city, mex

I need help choosing a good, ie safe and cheap, way to get from UNAM (Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México) to Aeropuerto Internacional Benito Juárez (MEX) at night. I was thinking about taking the Metro (to Copilco station) but people are telling me it is too dangerous for foreigners to take the Metro at night.

My flight leaves at 10pm so I was thinking about catching the Metro at 7pm.

Do you think taking the Metro is too dangerous? What other ways do I have to get there then?

Answer (score 4):

I took (pretty much) that exact trip last week at a bit later time, and didn't feel the slightest bit in danger. The metro is crowded with all kinds of normal folks. You can't beat 5 pesos for transportation that far, and it shouldn't vary much with traffic etc. You should be able to get a seat for many of the stops since the University is at the end of the line.

You could also take a taxi, of course.

The campus is huge, make sure you know how to get to your transportation.

[image]

If you want to increase comfort and reduce risk, you can use a radio taxi from the University- it's something like 25km so maybe $15 US or so, and you may have to leave an hour or more as well at rush hour.. don't know I only used the metro.

Comment: I personally don't recommend people to use the DF metro for the airport if they've got luggage and are not really familiar with how the system and its pickpockets work. I do use it myself and I have never been pickpocketed but I have been with friends multiple times when one or all of my friends lost valuables. If you do use it wait at the first or last carriage and stand in a corner with your stuff even if there's a seat. Wait for a couple of trains if the first ones are really full. It helps if you're big and look street-wise.

Comment: there won't be any luggage for me. How long does it take to get to the airport? My flight leaves at 10pm, so would it be better to get on the train by 7pm? or earlier? Is it easy to transfer to different line?

Comment: @hippietrail It's too crowded for luggage other than a pack, but it didn't seem any worse than taking the subway in New York or Shenzhen. It might be worse coming *from* the airport because you could be targeted but I didn't detect danger there either (on a Sunday afternoon when things were not too crowded)- I've foiled a couple pickpocketing attempts in other places and lost some small stuff a couple times earlier, so I'm not completely depending on luck.

Comment: @JoshLee It's an old system so there are almost no escalators, which bothered me more than it should (maybe the thin polluted air). No zones so you just buy a ticket and ride to your destination. Transfers are well-marked and easy for the most part. It's about 20 stops and two transfers (or 24 stops and one transfer) from the University to the airport, and about another couple hundred meters to the terminal, and the terminal is really long, so I would allow at least an hour (1.5 for the paranoid). Finding the entrance to the metro is not always easy, but those particular stops are no problem.

Comment: @hippietrail Why do you recommend avoiding seats when available? Is their MO physical confrontation? I always feel safer with a solid wall rather than strangers who may be in collusion behind me.

Comment: Without luggage and in that part of the evening should make it safer. I've gone at rush hour with a big backpack and small frontpack several times, but not for six years now. Certain stations and parts of certain lines are worse than others for. It's harder to defend your luggage crowded into a seat and you can't see behind you. Organized gangs of thieves communicate with hand signs. I try to make eye contact with other passengers too.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out! I think I will take the metro to go to the airport and hopefully I won't get pickpocketed by gangs or others. Another question i have is that how much would it cost to go to airport station from coplico which is located near by universidad station? only 5 pesos? Is there a machine to buy ticket? another question is that would it be better to transfer to centro medico to take line 9 and tranfer one more time at pantitlan to go to the airport or take all the way to la raza?

Comment: There is only one zone. 5 pesos everywhere. People line up to buy tickets at a wicket there are probably machines too don't remember- sometimes the lines are long (watch your stuff if it's busy)- if you buy a stored value RFID card (10 pesos plus the value) you can just tap it. I'm not sure how long the single fare tickets are valid, maybe someone else knows. Your last question- I think it's a roughly a wash time wise, if your seat is comfortable the single transfer might be better, but apparently the corridor to transfer at [La Raza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_La_Raza) is quite long.

Comment: You might want to consider your transfer decision based on the day of the week you are traveling, on business days M-F, around 7pm (rush hour) Pantitlan is one of the most crowded stations. Also keep in time you are supposed to arrive at the airport 3 hours early for international flights and 2 for domestic flights.